# Strange console error appears in localhost

Tags: javascript, console

I work on websites and sometimes have to use the console on my browser. However, this is being impeded by a looping text input from 'content.js'. It keeps looping the lines "retry page load *** websiteRoot ***" Is there an explanation for this?

I tried looking for the error in the code but it only says line two which has all of the code in content.js on a single line. The problem itself isn't harmful but I'm sure that it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: If this is happening on multiple independent websites, the script might come from a browser extension you have installed.

Comment: What do you mean by "*looping text input*"?